# Update function is not working in MEAN Stack using node.js and angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

Hello I am beginner in mean stack and I want to update a record using update

function I did save record successfully but update function is not working.

I want to update a particular object basses on the id. But it is not working.

I am using this function to update the record in **node js file**

```
  module.exports.useredit = function (req, res)
    {
        var user = new Usermodel();
        user = req.body.dataToModify;
        console.log(user);
        user.update({ _id:user._id },user);
    };
```

when I use  `console.log(user);` updating data show like this

```
{ _id: '5846692617e0575c0e0c2211',
  password: 123456,
  email: 'shahjad.ahmad89@gmail.com',
  name: 'shahjad232324324324',
  __v: 0 }
```

but data is not updating. error message showing  when I used

```
 user.update({ _id:user._id },user);
```

error is

```
user.update is not a function</h1>↵<h2></h2>↵<pre>TypeError: user.update is not a function↵    at module.exports.useredit (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\controller\usercontroller.js:102:10)↵    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)↵    at next (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)↵    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)↵    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)↵    at C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22↵    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)↵    at next (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)↵    at Function.handle (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:176:3)↵    at router (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:46:12)↵    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)↵    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)↵    at C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7↵    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)↵    at next (C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)↵    at C:\Users\Ahmad\ticket\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:618:15</pre>↵"
```

how to resloved it and how to update data into mongodb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

`module.exports.useredit = function (req, res){
      var id   = req.params.id,
          body = req.body,
          options = {
            upsert: true,
            new   : true
          }
      mongoDB.User.findOneAndUpdate({_id:id)}, body, options, function(err, user) {
        if(err){res.json(err)}else{res.json(user)}
      }
  }`

Note, mongoDB.user.findOneAndUpdate, the "mongoDB" is generic. This is your reference name to your MongoDB Schema whatever you named it.

Comment: what  mongoDB.User.findOneAndUpdate in this line what is User

Comment: That is typically referencing a MongoDB Schema in another file, I am not sure how you have your file structure. Seems like you might not have this, just take off mongoDB.

Answer (score 1):

You Could also try

```
user.update({ _id:user._id },$set{user});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
user.findOneAndUpdate({_id:user._id}, user, {upsert:true}, function(err, doc){
    if (err) 
       return res.send(500, { error: err });
    return res.send("userdata updated successfully");
});
```

here, "upsert = true" option creates the object if that doesn't exist.

It is false by default.